# Is it possible to apply star sizing with a stackpanel like you do with a grid in xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml

With a grid, i can say that i want one element to take up 3/4 of the page and one to take up 1/3 of the page by using width = "3*" and width = "1*"

Is it possible to do the same with Stackpanels? Or is the only way to do it by placing the stackpanels inside a grid?

Comment: Size of any control determines by its parent. I think Grid is better in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

In the .NET Framework, there are a number of different `Panel` classes. Some of them like the `Grid` and `DockPanel` provide resizing capabilities that resize the `Panel` children, while others don't. Generally, the ones that provide this functionality have a cost in terms of CPU and/or RAM.

Therefore, when requiring a `Panel` for simple layout purposes, these `Panel` types should be avoided and a simple `StackPanel` should be used instead. Other times, we require this extra functionality and so we should use one of these more expensive `Panel`s.

Please see the [Panels Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN for a much fuller description of the .NET `Panel`s.

So, to actually answer your question(s), no, a `StackPanel` cannot use similar sizing capabilities as the `Grid` and you can't do what you want even if you place `StackPanel`s inside a `Grid` because although the `Grid`'s cells may change size when the parent is resized, the `StackPanel`s contained within will not.